# Where can I find ‘The Common Law: Judicial Impartiality and Judge-Made Law’?

Tags: common-law, education, legal-history, legal-research, legal-concepts

I’m working on the translation of a document, which quotes a substantial part of this text: ‘The Common Law: Judicial Impartiality and Judge-Made Law’ by H. K. Luke.
After some research, I realized that this text is relatively important since it’s often cited in different articles and university courses.

Would anyone know where I can find it? I have no idea about its exact nature: Book? Article? Chapter? Course?

Comment: It is an article in The Law Quarterly Review, 1992 29–88.  I cannot find the article without paying, their site is [here](https://www.sweetandmaxwell.co.uk/Product/Academic-Law/Law-Quarterly-Review-The/Journal/30791431).

Comment: Most university law libraries would have a copy. So would many state supreme court law libraries which are usually available to the general public. Sometimes preprints can be found at the Social Science Research Network (the arXiv of social sciences). But this is probably too old for that.

Comment: Often you can correspond with the author, H.K. Lucke, and a get a copy that way, if the author is still living (the name of the author in your citation is misspelled). At the time he was an Honorary Professor, University of Queensland and Professor Emeritus, University of Adelaide, however, so it is likely that Professor Lucke is deceased.

Comment: I didn't find it on LQR, certainly it's an 1982 article and LQR has been created only in 1985.

Comment: I did send an email to the Professor H.K. Luke , but without any answer. Maybe because of the jetlag.